# QGIS 3.4 : Add points to exact locations?

Tags: qgis-3

I would like to add several coordinates at specific British National Grid Easting and Northing values. I know this can be done by bringing in a .csv, but I want to know is there a way to manually enter the numbers in QGIS 3.4, and then the point moves to that location ? I've read that in QGIS 2.*x* there was a plugin called **Numerical Vertex Editor** that doesn't seem to exist for 3.*x* ?

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS 3.*x*, create a point, choose the node tool, right-click on a snapped point and select Vertex editor.
A new panel appear and you can enter the true coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

The node tool has been mentioned. If you are in projected coordinate system, you can also use the "Advanced Digitizing panel" and lock the X and Y fields. Use the second button to lock continuously. Then your point will go to these coordinates.

[image]

Comment: The only restriction for this tool is to work with a projected coordinate system. It's no use with WGS 84 for example. In this case, the British National Grid is a projected SCR, it will work.

Comment: Indeed, I added your note.

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat plugin that does a fantastic one-dialog job, [Lat Lon Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/). Would be great if it was Core.