# How to add points using coordinates to QGIS without having to create a CSV?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, point, coordinates

Is there a way that I can add single points to QGIS (v3.4) by inputting coordinates directly into QGIS, rather than creating a CSV and adding them that way?

I know there used to be a plugin that could do this in previous versions, but it doesn't seem available in 3.4.

Comment: Create a point, right-click on it with the Vertex tool and change coordinates, look here for details : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311235/93097.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QGIS 3.4 : Add points to exact locations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312083/qgis-3-4-add-points-to-exact-locations)

The thing is to look for the [Lat Lon Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/) plugin. You can enter the point coordinates and it will create the entity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Answered by J. Monticolo in the comment above:**

Create a point, right-click on it with the Vertex tool and change coordinates, look here for details : http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311235/93097